ASP.NET MVC custom errors with areas
If I set custom errors in the main web.config like this:
<customErrors mode="On">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Home/NotFound"/>
</customErrors>

Then it works fine in the main part of the site.
However, there are several login areas where the needs are different (like I want to be emailed if a user is hitting pages not on the navbar), but trying to set the same thing in the sub area web.config doesn't work.
My question is: how do I configure different custom error pages for each area?
